# Use a value of JSON within ng-Repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have this JSON:

```
var myObj = {
    {"key1":"value1", "key2":5, "key3":"value3" },
    {"key1":"value4", "key2":2, "key3":"value5" },
    {"key1":"value6", "key2":4, "key3":"value6" },
}
```

I want to use this for ng-Repeat. But the values of "key2" must iterate within their own ng-repeat. So something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in myObj">
   <li> {{x.key1}} </li>
   <ul ng-repeat="y in x.key2">
      <li></li>
   </ul>
   <li> {{x.key3}} </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously this doesn't work. 
The result of the first array should like this (5 li-elements should be created):

```
<ul>
  <li> value1 </li>
  <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
  </ul>
  <li> value 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom method `range` that on `range(n)` will return `[1,2,3,  .. n]`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <ul ng-repeat="x in myObj">

   <li> {{x.key1}} </li>
   <ul ng-repeat="y in range(x.key2)">
      <li></li>
   </ul>
   <li> {{x.key3}} </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.myObj = [
    {"key1":"value1", "key2":5, "key3":"value3" },
    {"key1":"value4", "key2":2, "key3":"value5" },
    {"key1":"value6", "key2":4, "key3":"value6" },
];


$scope.range = function(count){
  var items = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
    items.push(i) 
  } 

  return items;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFBeugHnCjJZ86AmvZKA?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your controller as

```
 $scope.getNumber = function(count){
      return new Array(count);  
    }
```

and update your html as

```
 <ul ng-repeat="x in myObj">
       <li> {{x.key1}} </li>
       <ul ng-repeat="y in getNumber(x.key2)">
          <li></li>
       </ul>
   <li> {{x.key3}} </li>
</ul>
```